# Ant sshexec task unable to execute remote script file separate from session

Tags: bash, unix, jenkins, ant, jboss

I have an Ant script to be called from Jenkins that - after other deployment tasks - start a JBoss server. The deployment package already contains an startup script which wraps up the JBoss run script:

```
[...]/bin/run.sh -b ip -c config >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

The startup script runs fine when manually executed (i.e ssh to the server and sudo ./startup.sh)

Now I'm having trouble invoking this startup script from `sshexec` task. The task can execute the startup script and JBoss does gets spun up but will terminate as soon as the task return and move on to the next task - similar to running the `run.sh` directly and closing the session.

My task is pretty standard

```
<sshexec host="host" username="username" password="password"
command="echo password | sudo -S sh ${JBOSS_HOME}/server/config/startup.sh" />
```

I'm confused. Shouldn't the startup script above covered starting up JBoss separately from the session already? Any idea how to solve this?

The remote system is Redhat 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found it. Still need to combine `nohup` and background running with the startup script. Plus the "dirty workaround" from here 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91065/nohup-sudo-does-not-prompt-for-passwd-and-does-nothing (was actually brilliant)

End result:

```
echo password | sudo -S env && sudo sh -c 'nohup startup.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &'
```